# Cannot change Core Data property in Swift for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, core-data

In Swift (2.3 currently) I have an `NSManagedObject` that Ive received through a fetch request, that has a property on it that is contained in a typical `Core Data` Set.  I want to loop through those `Core Data` objects in the Set, and change properties on them, but Im told that I cannot because they are `let` constants.  Heres my code :

```
for mediaEntity in aMemory.mediaEntities! {
    mediaEntity.remoteId = 0
}
```

Which gives the error `Cannot assign to property : mediaEntity is a let constant`

The Core Data property Im trying to change is defined like this :

```
extension MemoryEntity {
   @NSManaged public var mediaEntities: NSSet?
}
```

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Try var entity = mediaEntity then entity.remoteId = 0.

Comment: Did try that.  Gives the error : `Cannot assign to property: 'entity' is immutable

Comment: Ah wait - so now I can fix that by casting the var to the type it needs to be, MediaEntity.  Which works!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: How did you even manage that? If mediaEntities is an NSSet then you at least need some typecast? So (mediaEntity as? MyEntityName)?.remoteId = 0

Comment: Yeh weirdly, I can access the properties to read them, just not assign to them.  Theres other code in that loop that reads the properties too.  Only when I try to change them do I start getting the errors.  Quirk of Swift, probably fixed in 3

Comment: Actually I was trying this in Swift 3 and lets you do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with NSSet you need to at least typecast the object. The example I have looks like this:

```
entity.activities?.forEach { ($0 as? ActivityEntity)?.id = UUID().uuidString }
```

A more flexible code would then be:

```
entity.activities?.forEach {

      guard let activity = $0 as? ActivityEntity else {
          return // Incorrect type. Should never happen
      }

      activity.id = UUID().uuidString
}
```

Comment: No force unwrapping here.